# A convenient way of configuring non-type template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, configuration, c-preprocessor

I am writing a generic framework which relies heavily on templates. An external python script reads a configuration file and compiles the framework with pre-processor symbols based on the configuration.

Suppose the code:

```
#include "all_symbols.h" // has a default for MY_TYPE 
#include "config_symbols.h" // may or may not re-define MY_TYPE
template <typename T = MY_TYPE>
struct SomeStruct {...};
```

The header `all_symbols.h` looks like this:

```
struct None {};
#define MY_TYPE None
... // set to None all the other symbols
```

The header `config_symbols.h` is created by the script to re-define the symbols based on the configuration file. This header may define only some of the symbols, which is why `all_symbols.h` is needed.

A key property of this scheme is that if `SomeStruct` gets instantiated without `MY_TYPE` being re-defined in `config_symbols.h`, then the user will get a compile-time error.

I am looking for a way to extend this scheme to non-type template parameters:

```
template <bool flag = MY_VALUE>
struct SomeStruct {...};
```

The problem is that the mentioned above key property is not kept. Namely, `MY_VALUE` needs to be defined in `all_symbols.h` as either `false` or `true`, so that the user will not get a compile-time error if he instantiates `SomeStruct`, but fails to specify `MY_VALUE` in the configuration.

I could work around this problem by substituting *non-type* template parameters with *type* ones, but that is kind of artificial. Is there another workaround?

Comment: I don't get it. "A key property of this scheme is that if SomeStruct gets instantiated without MY_TYPE being re-defined in config_symbols.h, then the user will get a compile-time error." So why not omit MY_TYPE in all_symbols, in which case an omission in config_symbols will cause a compile-time error irrespective of what kind of template it is?

Comment: @AmiTavory This would cause a problem if `SomeStruct` is not instantiated. The configuration defines only symbols for the templates that need to be instantiated. However, the compiler insists that *all* default values of template parameters be defined, even for templates that never get instantiated.

Comment: Can you outline the solution for the typed case which you found acceptable?

Comment: @AmiTavory I think it is outlined in the question. Could you please ask more specifically?